# Is it possible to hook up macbook build in keyboard to Ubuntu PC?

Tags: keyboard

I need to work on both: Mac Pro and Ubuntu PC.

I would like to use one keyboard. It is more less simple to do with external Mac keyboard, but how to do it with build-in one?

External is not convenient, because I use 3 or 4 screens (including laptop one) and the whole 'work env' gets either too wide or too deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/)? They say that it  lets you easily share your mouse and **keyboard** between multiple computers on your desktop.

There are some [videos on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=synergy+macbook+&oq=synergy+macbook) which show how it works.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. Synergy would be the answer if it worked :( Tried two configurations (to pick server) and at least two versions. Mouse works, keyboard doesn't.

Comment: it was a fight, but it worked eventually!